# Mint does not wake up from suspend

Tags: linux-mint, mouse, suspend, freeze

I recently installed Mint on my laptop, where previously Windows 8.1 was installed. Whenever I suspend the system, it is completely frozen after waking up. I can not move the mouse, cant use the keyboard or the touchscreen (after waking up).

I was looking for a solution, so I tried this [answer by Matt West](https://askubuntu.com/a/731840/697457).

After following the instructions, i can suspend and wake up, but i can not use the touchpad, a mouse, the touchscreen or wifi anymore (before and after suspending). But the keyboard works properly, so i undid the changes.

Can anyone help me to fix that suspend issue?